# TYPO3 8.7.2-8.7.3 & fluidpages blank page

Tags: fluid, fluid-layout, typo3-8.x

After updating from TYPO3 8.7.1 to 8.7.2(8.7.3) in frontend just blank page - nothing rendered. All empty `<head>`, `<body>`, etc. Also updated to last FLUX, FLUID, fluidpages, fluidcontent, vhs. No result. After downgrade to 8.7.1 all works.

Tried also clear instance - again no results. Looks like 'fluidpagesRawTemplate' which should render all frontend does not call at all.

Somebody faced with this problem?

PS:

- My EXT use 'fluidpages'+'flux' for backend and frontend layouts.
- Have no errors or warnings in TYPO3 logs or PHP server logs.

Comment: Check your log history, If getting any error then solve it.

Comment: There is problem. No logs warning or errors, no php errors. Nothing. Looks like TS Object empty.

Comment: set **'displayErrors' => '1', 'sqlDebug' => '1',** in LocaConfiguration.php file. if getting any error... also add this typoscript in setup config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0

Comment: I know) Really no errors, event all dubug mode switch on. Looks like Daniel right. Problem in config.metaCharset. I still testing, after will commit his ansver. Thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are affected by a [regression](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/81634) that was introduced in TYPO3 8.7.2. Look for `config.metaCharset = UTF-8` in you configuration and remove it or change it to `config.metaCharset = utf-8`.

This bug should not be present in 8.7.3 anymore. Please update your TYPO3 to 8.7.3

Comment: Looks like you right). But as i type before. The same situation in 8.7.3